# How to obtain multiple values from Like condition in Lookup SQL Override using input port?

Tags: lookup, informatica-powercenter

I have to lookup 3 tables in my scenario. 
Following is an excerpt from the Lookup table. One of them has approximately 6 million rows, the other two have 500 rows each, and are on separate linked servers.

LOOKUP_TABLE
Invoice_number  Invoice Date
123             05/05/2013
123A            05/05/2014
123B            05/05/2015

I have invoice numbers and dates coming in from a source file. For eg:
Source Row:- src_invoice: 123 Invoice Date: 05/05/2015
I want all the rows which have invoice number like '123_'

Thus my LOOKUP SQL override query will be 
select * from LOOKUP_TABLE where invoice_number like src_invoice+'_'     ;

But this is giving me an error since the input_port cannot be substituted in the sql override.

Now I don't want to use Uncached lookup since I have to lookup 3 such lookup_tables, having 6 million,  500 and 500 rows each and on separate linked servers. Reaching out to the linked servers for looking up every source invoice number thrice would take a lot of time.

The reason I want multiple rows is because I want two things from the lookup tables.
1.) Check whether  src_date = Lookup_table.Invoice_Date, then mark as duplicate
2.) If src_date != Lookup_table.Invoice_Date, then append alphabet to max(invoice_number).
Thus new src_invoice will be 123C

Any advise is appreciated. If you think my approach to this problem is wrong, kindly provide an alternate solution which does not require using the lookup sql override.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all: with 6M rows it would be better to use a `Joiner Transformation` instead of a `Lookup`. And carefully choose the `Master` node on the Joiner.

Next: the SQL Override here is executed to create the cache. You can't create cache for a single invoice and try to read it for all of them. This would be useful for `uncached lookup` only - which you don't want (and should not) use in this scenario. In fact, in this scenario you don't need any SQL Override at all.

By the way: the `_` in SQL will match exactly one character. If you need anything that starts with '123' and may have more than 4 characters, use `%` instead.